# C: how to check if a particular variable has been passed as argument

Tags: c, function

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct{
int A; 
char* B;
}MYTYPE;

MYTYPE sample;
int nCount; 

void doSomething(int A, MYTYPE* B)
{
//doing something inside this function.
}

doSomething(nCount, &sample);
```

Is there a way in my function doSomething() to check if the second argument passsed was exactly `sample`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

```
if(B == &sample)
{
  printf("Get your own, don't use sample!\n");
}
```

note that your call is wrong, you need:

```
doSomething(nCount, &sample);
                    ^
                    |
               IMPORTANT!
```

Since the function expects an address. It will not build, as written in the question.

Comment: @Sunny Why wouldn't it? C is a platform-idependent language.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can simply compare the addresses.

Remember that a pointer to something is actually the address of that something. So you could do like this:

```
void doSomething(int A, MYTYPE* B)
{
    if (B == &sample)
    {
        printf("B is sample\n";
    }
}
```